# rc.local doesn't execute anything

Tags: server, ssh, autostart, jekyll

I only have SFTP access and SSH access, it's virtual server running Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to get jekyll to auto-start whenever I start/reboot the server.

In the ssh terminal I can just enter

```
cd /var/www/html/testme2 && jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0 -w --incremental
```

That works just fine, but when I enter

```
/var/www/html/testme2 jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0 -w --incremental
```

into the rc.local. Nothing happens. I tested if rc.local is being executed with echo "rc.local runnin" > /var/www/html/running.txt , and the file was created with the entry in it.

I tested sh rc.local and this was the output

> rc.local: 14: rc.local: /var/www/html/testme: Permission denied

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/var/www/html/testme/` and `cd /var/www/html/testme` are different things

Comment: I know, but neither variant works.

Comment: The & is critical too.  Why didn't you just type what works at the command line?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. With or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why I did

```
/var/www/html/testme2 jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0 -w --incremental
```

but adding this

```
cd /var/www/html/testme2 && jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0 -w --incremental
```

to rc.local works just fine, and jekyll auto-starts.